# Macro recorded VBA not creating same column graph

Tags: vba, excel, graph, charts

This is my data in Excel, I am trying to create a column graph from it

[image: picture of excel data]

Data in column A is for the column labels and data in column B is for the column heights.

This is a picture of the graph I'm looking for:
[image: manual and desired graph]

I need to do this through VBA so I created the graph manually whilst recording a macro. I got this code:

```
Sub Macro5()
Range("A1:B10").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Report!$A$1:$B$10")
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).Overlap = 0
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 0
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Frequency"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Frequency"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 9).ParagraphFormat
    .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
    .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 9).Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Bold = msoFalse
    .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
    .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
    .Size = 14
    .Italic = msoFalse
    .Kerning = 12
    .Name = "+mn-lt"
    .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
    .Spacing = 0
    .Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
End Sub
```

Now, when I run this macro again, it doesn't give me the same graph that I created when I recorded this macro.

This is the graph I get when I run the macro:
[image: incorrect graph]

So, my question is why is it doing this and how do I fix it? How would I make a graph like the one I made manually from the data I have?

Recording the macro didn't work at all for me and gives me a completely different graph as you can see.

To summarize I created a graph manually and recorded a macro but running the macro doesn't create the graph I created before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the programmatic steps you need to take to replicate your chart.

You must have initially followed steps that aren't the same as the ones taken by the chart wizard. The generated code from the chart wizard isn't always that helpful.

The steps:

- create the data in the worksheet
- create a new shape with a chart and get the chart reference
- assign the ***data*** to the chart
- get the first series in the chart
- assign the ***labels*** to the series
- change the 'GapWidth' property on the chart's first 'ChartGroup' to get that ***chunky*** look
- set chart title

Just drop this code into an empty module and run it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateGraph()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngLabels As Range
    Dim rngData  As Range
    Dim shpChart As Shape
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim srs As Series

    ' set a reference to worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' get ranges for labels and data
    Set rngLabels = ws.Range("A1:A10")
    Set rngData = ws.Range("B1:B10")

    'uncomment if you want to fake up some data for the this
    'ws.Cells.Delete
    'rngLabels.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100))
    'rngData.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array(0, 1, 4, 9, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 6))

    ' create a chart shape, get chart reference and set source data
    Set shpChart = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered)
    Set cht = shpChart.Chart
    cht.SetSourceData Source:=rngData, PlotBy:=xlColumns

    ' update the series object with labels
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(1)
    srs.XValues = rngLabels

    ' make the graph 'chunky'
    cht.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 0

    ' set chart title
    cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Frequency"

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This works but is there a way to do this without having to input those values manually into the array in the transpose function in the code? Is there a way to make it get the array from the sheet? because those values aren't always the same

Comment: Sure just comment out the `ws.Cells.Delete` and the two lines with the array transpose and it will take the data off your sheet instead. I will update the code for this.

Comment: Thanks, this works well, can I ask what the purpose of the delete line and the transpose lines is?

Comment: Sure - it was just when I was testing the code and wanted a blank worksheet and the same test data every time without having to re-key it in.